# How to use a distribution to represent a stationary time series?

Tags: time-series, distributions, normal-distribution, autocorrelation

Suppose I have a stationary time series, if I pool the data together it will look like a Gaussian distribution. However, I don't think it is proper since it might be auto correlated and Gaussian distribution assumes iid.

1. What's the proper way to represent this series using distribution?
2. Suppose I do ACF and PACF test and there's no auto correlation, can I directly use a Gaussian distribution to represent it?

Comment: Serial dependence has nothing to do with the unconditional distribution. The distribution will be nongaussian, it will be a mixture.